# Why does the A-4 Skyhawk sit nose-up when on ground?

Tags: aircraft-design, landing-gear, douglas-a-4-skyhawk

The rear of the plane is nearer to the ground, while the front part of the plane is away from the ground (see image below).

Other planes are more flat.

I think it was for high AoA but these planes are carrier operated so I don't think there is much sense for that.

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A4ABCweb.jpg))

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking.  Are you commenting that it dits nose high in its landing gear?

Comment: The landing gears arent the same height which gives the plane a "taildragger posture". Why?

Comment: @CarloFelicione Its best observable in the Wikipedia. Open its article and CTRL+F "color scheme".  (Wikipedia is banned I cant give you the link for the image)

Comment: I think most of what you are seeing is just perspective. I think the "flat A4" in the upper right corner may be parked on a hill or something. I'm not sure how the F4 is relevant to the A4 question though?

Comment: @RonBeyer as an example for an "non tilted" plane

Comment: The A-4 had a mechanically-simple but effective high-lift system that relied on gravity and air pressure to automatically deploy. Not sure about the actual mechanism, but I remember reading somewhere that the high pitch angle helped the deployment.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This was pretty common on naval aircraft from that era which used the launch bridle catapult interface. It gave the aircraft a high angle of attack during launch and helped the aircraft get clear of the bridle at the end of the launch stroke. It's noticeable on a wide variety of aircraft, including the F7U-3, F4D, A-5, F9F, F8, Super Etendard, Buccaneer, F3H, just to name a few.

Even the F-4 did. The nose landing gear oleo strut could be extended to give a nose high squat for cat shots:

[image]
([theaviationgeekclub.com](https://theaviationgeekclub.com/vintage-video-shows-phinal-f-4-phantom-launch-from-a-u-s-navy-aircraft-carrier/))

Comment: I like this answer better than mine.  As a side note you could note that the A-4 gear was designed to be tall overall to give sufficient ground clearance to carry a nuclear weapon.  Sources: For corroboration, "The long landing-gear struts were dictated by clearance requirements for large stores carried beneath the wings on either side and between the main landing-gear legs." https://history.nasa.gov/SP-468/ch12-7.htm (thanks ymb1), http://www.f16.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=27254 .

Comment: The latter suggests that there were issues with the nose dipping too low during catapult launches and less-than-optimal landings but it's still not clear whether the tall nose gear was actually intended to help prevent that in any way.

Comment: Article of peripheral interest on "bridle catchers" and launch bridles: https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/7099/__trashed-9 .  Also https://www.patriotspoint.org/news-and-events/navy-catapult-launch-improvement-1962/ .  Google "launch bridle" for more.

Comment: Also http://thanlont.blogspot.com/2011/01/catapult-innovations.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Then why doesn't F4 have that too? After all its designed to be an carrier aircraft with folding Wings right?

Comment: Ah but the F4 did.  The nose landing gear oleo strut could be extended to give a nose high squat for cat shots https://theaviationgeekclub.com/vintage-video-shows-phinal-f-4-phantom-launch-from-a-u-s-navy-aircraft-carrier/

Comment: "The nose landing gear oleo strut could be extended" ... Fleet Air Arm F-4K even moreso, apparently.